# Bonjour with Macruby

Tags: bonjour, macruby

I understand using Dnssd within ruby but it seems that dnssd does not load in Macruby.  I was curious if anyone knew of something like dnssd or could give an example way to browse bonjour on a network using macruby.  Ive been told this is possible through the scriptingbridge but im unsure how this actually works.